# Save Failed Index out of bounds - Eclipse , while saving file after making changes very time i got this exception

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I save file in eclipse, I am getting `IndexOutOfBound` exception, please check below link for screenshot.

[image: Eclipse error]

The OS is Windows.
Still missing:

- java version
- minimum code illustrating the error

Comment: Please take a moment to read these- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.